# Would you help me with "help grammar"

Tags: verbs

Would you please help me with this verb Grammer?
The volunteers help........ The project

1. complete
2. completing
3. to complete
4. 1 and 3

What I know is we add ING to the second verb

Comment: See the linked duplicate.  Usually  "help do" or "help to do", not "help doing"